# Minimal Javascript to embed twitter feed into my html?

Tags: javascript, html, rss, twitter

What is the minimal Javascript to embed twitter feed into my html ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [many ways](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/10-awesome-ways-to-integrate-twitter-with-your-website/) to integrate Twitter on your website. [Widgets](http://twitter.com/widgets) are particularly easy to add.

Answer (score 6):

[Tweet! By Sea of Clouds](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/) is a very simple jQuery powered Twitter feed. [Juitter is also good](http://juitter.com/) and simple to integrate.

Comment: Both links seem to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

You could do worse than this simple YUI Gallery widget:

http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/twitter-status